# My table is going out of the right margin, please help how to extend it vertically of fix it?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[hbpt!]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Synthesis} &
  \textbf{Technique} &
  \textbf{Product} &
  \textbf{Temperature (°C)} &
  \textbf{properties} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{SiC powders} & Reduction of silica by carbon                    & $\beta$-SiC     & 1800               & Fine   powder           \\ \cline{2-5} 
                             & Siliconization   of carbon                         & $\beta$-SiC     & 1380   or 1200-300 & Coarse   powder         \\ \cline{2-5} 
                             & Chemical   vapor deposition (CVD)                  & $\beta$-SiC     & -                  & Fine   powder           \\ \cline{2-5} 
 &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Liquid-phase raw materials\\ and precursor method\end{tabular} &
  $\beta$-SiC &
  1600-1800°C &
  Fine   powder \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{SiC in bulk} & Lely   method                                      & $\alpha$-SiC     & $\sim$2700°C       & Large   single crystals \\ \cline{2-5} 
                             & Molten   metal method                              & Polytypes & High   Temperature & Inorganic   crystals    \\ \cline{2-5} 
                             & \multirow{2}{*}{Chemical   vapor deposition (CVD)} & $\alpha$-SiC     & 2000-2300°C        & single   crystals       \\ \cline{3-5} 
                             &                                                    & $\beta$-SiC     & \textless{}2000°C  & single   crystals       \\ \cline{2-5} 
                             & Aqueous   solution method                          & SiC       & -                  & Polycrystalline   films \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Classification of methods for SiC synthesis (powders and bulk) \cite{3}}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ, how wide the text block is (or, alternatively, how wide the left and right hand margins are), and which font size is in effect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document.`  Seems to be duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to recommend allowing automatic line breaks in columns 2, 4, and 5. This may be achieved by employing a `tabularx` environment; see below for a specific implementation. I would also employ hanging indentation to make it easier to see where the cells are.

Furthermore, I would like to suggest that you get rid of the `\multirow` directives and replace all `\cline` directives with (vertical) whitespace, in order to give the table a more open and inviting look. Separately, do consider employing the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of the  basic `\hline` and `\cline` macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\hangindent=0.75em\hangafter=1}X}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Polytypes} % measure width of column #3

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbpt!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L p{\mylen} L L @{}}
\toprule
  \textbf{Synthesis} &
  \textbf{Technique} &
  \textbf{Product} &
  \textbf{Temperature} &
  \textbf{Properties} \\ 
\midrule
SiC powders
  & Reduction of silica by carbon
  & $\beta$-SiC
  & 1800°C
  & Fine powder \\ 
  \addlinespace 
  & Siliconization of carbon 
  & $\beta$-SiC     
  & 1380°C or \mbox{1200--1300°C}
  & Coarse powder \\ 
  \addlinespace 
  & Chemical vapor deposition (CVD) 
  & $\beta$-SiC & --  & Fine powder  \\ 
  \addlinespace 
  & Liquid-phase raw materials and precursor method 
  & $\beta$-SiC 
  & 1600--1800°C 
  & Fine powder \\ 
\midrule
SiC in bulk
  & Lely method 
  & $\alpha$-SiC 
  & $\approx$2700°C 
  & Large single crystals \\ 
  \addlinespace 
  & Molten metal method 
  & Polytypes 
  & High temperature 
  & Inorganic crystals \\ 
  \addlinespace 
  & Chemical vapor deposition (CVD) 
    & $\alpha$-SiC \newline $\beta$-SiC 
    & 2000--2300°C \newline $<$\,2000°C
    & single crystals \newline single crystals \\ 
  \addlinespace   
  & Aqueous solution method 
  & SiC
  & --
  & Polycrystalline films \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Classification of methods for SiC synthesis (powders 
         and bulk) \cite{3}}
\label{tab:SiC_methods}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. can you please share some information about how to prepare good looking tables for big reports? so that i can change all the existing tables in my document.